# VQmod on new VPS not writing vqcache files or log files

Tags: php, linux, opencart, vqmod

I am just moving an opencart site to a staging server and have vqmod installed in the site however I can't get vqmod to create the vqcache files and it isn't even logging any errors in the vqmod/log folder. I've basically set the directory structure to 777 to get it to work from a permissions point of view and everything is ownership user:www-data but still no joy.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone has a similar issue, it was a user groups issue, the ownership settings for the vqmod.php file were user:user rather than the required user:www-data

Comment: Could you point out where you found that user:www-data is required? I have the exact same issue for days. On a shared hosting package you can´t edit the ownership...

Comment: I just added a new NOT-vqmod extension and suddently vqmod stops working.

Answer (score 0):

You should actually set the permissions for your `vqmod.php` to be the same as your `index.php`in your main OpenCart folder, not alter the owner of the file. You should also set the permissions of the following be the same as your `/system/cache/` folder

```
/vqmod/
/vqmod/vqcache/
/vqmod/logs/
```

Comment: yeah, it was a new VPS just set up and the permissions of site level files were a bit all over the place. Vqmod doesn't give any form of reporting/logging when this is the issue though which is why it took me a while to sort out